# How to create a NodeJS Authorization middleware on a serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless-framework

I'd like to create a middleware that checks the authorization header, decodes the token and sends the decoded data to the actual function, just like you would by adding userData to the request and using next() on an Express server, so the actual function gets back the decoded data on the req and it can then check what content to display to the user (if any).

I'm using Lambda functions on a serverless framework.

This was the function on my Express NodeJS local server:

```
const authorizerFunc = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  try {
    if (
      req.headers.authorization &&
      req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer"
    ) {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    }
    if (!token) {
      req.userData = { userId: "", username: "" };
      next();
      return;
    }
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
    console.log("DECODED TOKEN", decodedToken);
    req.userData = {
      userId: decodedToken.userId,
      username: decodedToken.username,
      email: decodedToken.email,
    };
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    req.userData = { userId: "", username: "" };
    next();
    return;
  }
};
```

The question is, how do I create a Lambda function that does this and sends the decoded data to the real function?

Edit: is it bad if I decode the auth token directly in the functions at the very beginning? I don't think it would add huge complexity to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't have an actuall example for the serverless framework, but i can tell what you should do.

1. Create an Lambda Function to act as a Amazon API Gateway Lambda authorizer - you can see the documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html
2. make sure you do the validation logic what you have defined, and also return the context object in the response - which you can define your user data
3. add the Amazon API Gateway Lambda authorizer to the API Gateway - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html
4. If the authorization successful your rest api lambda can access the context object with the user data, which you customize in step 2

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried implementing it, but for some reason, I don't get back the context object with the data. Any idea why this is happening? This is what I'm returning:   
return {
      isAuthorized: true,
      context: {
        userId: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
      },
    };

Comment: should be, it is not in the `event` but in the `context` parameter of the lambda function

Comment: I figured out it sits in event.requestContext.authorizer.lambda. Weird, because I couldn't find this answer on the internet and simply logged the event and checked on CloudWatch and noticed a lambda object in that path, and tried to log it and casually realized it's where the context object sits.